# How to create an entity of a model with referenceProperty without the reference exists?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have two model classes Team and Student. Each Team entity has more than one Users entities, I think "one to many" is a proper model. I code like this:

```
class Team(db.Model):
    teamNmae = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    teamID = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
class Users(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    reference = db.ReferenceProperty(Team,collection_name=teamMembers)
```

Follow [this document](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling), I need to first create a Team entity, then create Users whose reference is set to this Team entity. But,here is the problem, I want to create User first, then User can create a Team. So, how to set reference when I create a User that no Team exists ?

**EDIT1**:

I write simple code to test if I can create a entity without its reference entity created.

```
  _author__ = 'Steven_yang'
import os
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import  db
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
defaultStu = [
    'qingWANG',
    'stevenYANG',
    'jingZHU',
    'conghuiHE',
    'lianDUAN',
    'xinHAO'
]
class Students(db.Model):
    #reference = db.ReferenceProperty(Team,collection_name='teamMember',required=False)
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
class Team(db.Model):
    teamName = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    teamID = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
def createStu():
    stu_count = Students.all().count(1)
    if stu_count == 0:
        for stu in defaultStu:
            newStu = Students(name = stu)

            newStu.put()
class testReferenceHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        createStu()
        self.render_page()
    def render_page(self):
        stus = Students.all().fetch(10)
        templateValues={}
        templateValues['stus'] = stus
        form = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'template/testref.html')
        renderForm = template.render(form,templateValues)
        self.response.out.write(renderForm)
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/testref',testReferenceHandler)],debug=True)
```

HTML file is:

```
<body>
    {% for s in stus%}
    <div>{{s.name}}</div>
    {% endfor%}
</body>
</html>
```

when I comment out the ReferenceProperty line, everything is fine. When I add the ReferenceProperty line, I got a **server error**. So, I can't create a entity without its reference created before?

Comment: Are you sure that you need one to many relationship, does the User can be only one team? If so, what stops creating the empty reference ?

Comment: Yes, each user can only join one team, but one team has many users. You mean when I create User, I set reference=None? I try this, but it doesn't for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set `reference` to `Team` model as `None` when creating a `User` instance?

Also change the last line your code snippet to:

```
reference = db.ReferenceProperty(Team,required=False)
```

i.e. add `required=False`. This is what is suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7550402/1211429).

Comment: I add required= False, and then I create newUser = Users(reference=None,....). But it doesn't work. :(

Comment: @stevenYANG Try not passing anything (i.e. not even the `None`) just don't pass `reference` arg. If that doesn't work, remove the `collection_name=teamMembers`.

Comment: @stevenYANG It should work: refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7550402/1211429) answer.

Comment: Does the reference property influence the way I query this class? I mean, can I use db.Gqlqurey("...") to query a class when this class has a reference?

Comment: This got me crazy. here is my code, I make comment on the line cause error.https://github.com/YifanYANG/team-app/commit/1c1329cc23ca4f5189194fde2729559a1df0e126

Comment: @stevenYANG Sorry dude, can't figure it out myself. You have to examine the exception's stack trace.

Comment: I add some code in the question. I still can't create a entity without its reference entity created.